# Exclude duplicates and capture only changes

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, gaps-and-islands

I have a scenario, where I have to exclude duplicates and capture only the changes. Also calculate the valid_from and valid_to on the fly. I have tried a query and it works but it is very slow in performance and it is failing with memory error .

**Input :** Only capture Entries where there is a change either in Amount/Check-In-Out.
Calculate Valid_from and Valid_to based on Date Changed.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

SQL I tried.

```
select * from (select   
  
    lead(start_date, "window_offset" - rn + 1, '9999-12-31') over (order by "grp" ) as valid_to,  
    case when rn = max(rn) over (partition by "grp") then 1 else 0 end as "isLastUpdate",  
    start_date as valid_from,* 
from (  
    select  
        min("DateChanged") over (partition by "grp") as start_date,  
        count(*) over (partition by "grp") as "window_offset",  
        row_number() over (partition by "grp" order by "DateChanged") as rn,  
        *  
from (
 select sum("isChanged") over (partition by OrderId order by "DateChanged") as "grp",*  
 from (  
        select   
            case when "Amount" = lag( "Amount" ) over (partition by OrderId  order by "DateChanged") and  
                      "Check-In" = lag( "Check-In" ) over (partition by OrderId order by "DateChanged") and
                      "Check-Out" = lag( "Check-Out" ) over (partition by OrderId order by "DateChanged")  
                      then 0  
                 else 1  
            end  "isChanged",       
            *  
        FROM  :in_table 
)
))
    where "isLastUpdate" = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your expected answer is unclear as to why you get `valid_from` as `8-mar-21` for the first `order_id` and `9-apr-21` for the second `order_id` as both `order_id`s have overlapping ranges but you take the least of the previous `check_out` and the next `check_in` for the first `order_id` and the greatest of those two for the second and it is inconsistent.

If you want to get `valid_from` as the greatest of either the current `check_in` or the previous `check_out`s and `valid_to` as the greatest of either the current `check_out` or the next `check_in` or, if there are no more rows, `9999-12-31` then:

```sql
SELECT orderid,
       amount,
       check_in,
       check_out,
       GREATEST(
         check_in,
         COALESCE(
           MAX(check_out) OVER (
             PARTITION BY orderid
             ORDER BY check_in, check_out
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
           ),
           check_in
         )
       ) AS valid_from,
       GREATEST(
         check_out,
         LEAD(check_in, 1, DATE '9999-12-31') OVER (
           PARTITION BY orderid ORDER BY check_in, check_out
         )
       ) AS valid_to
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (orderid, datechanged, amount, check_in, check_out) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-03-3', 12.12, DATE '2021-03-03', DATE '2021-03-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-03-3', 12.12, DATE '2021-03-03', DATE '2021-03-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-03-3', 12.12, DATE '2021-03-03', DATE '2021-03-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-03-8', 21.12, DATE '2021-03-08', DATE '2021-03-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-03-8', 21.12, DATE '2021-03-08', DATE '2021-03-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2021-04-4',  9.10, DATE '2021-04-04', DATE '2021-04-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2021-04-4',  9.10, DATE '2021-04-04', DATE '2021-04-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2021-04-4', 10.20, DATE '2021-04-04', DATE '2021-04-12' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ORDERID | AMOUNT | CHECK_IN | CHECK_OUT | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 12.12 | 2021-03-03 00:00:00 | 2021-03-10 00:00:00 | 2021-03-03 00:00:00 | 2021-03-10 00:00:00 |
> | 1 | 21.12 | 2021-03-08 00:00:00 | 2021-03-18 00:00:00 | 2021-03-10 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |
> | 2 | 9.1 | 2021-04-04 00:00:00 | 2021-04-09 00:00:00 | 2021-04-04 00:00:00 | 2021-04-09 00:00:00 |
> | 2 | 10.2 | 2021-04-04 00:00:00 | 2021-04-12 00:00:00 | 2021-04-09 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ab8534a8b1ed2397fb8e6599f32c6eb9)*

Comment: Valid_from and Valid_to is based on datechanged like till when the record is valid not on checkin checkout. So we can track the modifications.
For eg- If I want to pick the amount for Order Id on March 5 then I will get 12.12 and if I want on March 15 then I get 21.12 because the record changed during that time.

Comment: @Satheesh But why do you get 21.12 (the greater and later value) and not 12.12 when you pick an amount for `order_id` 1 on 9th March and you get 9.1 (the lower and earlier value) and not 10.2 when you pick an amount for `order_id` 2 on 5th April? What is the logic that you use to determine which value to pick when there are overlapping date ranges?

Comment: Datechanged is not always the checkin date. So I need to calculate valid_from and valid to based on Datechanged . and valid_from/valid_to is not overlapped at anytime.

Whenever there is a modification in the amount or checkin/checkout a new entry will be created with the new datechanged, When that happens I have to make the previous record invalid by updating the valid to as datechanged .

The new record validfrom should be datechanged and validto is 99991231. Not sure if i explained correct

Comment: @Satheesh So why for the first row in `order_id` of 2 is the `valid_from`/`valid_to` the 4th - 9th April and not 4th - 4th April as it is immediately superseded by the second row?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, that was the mistake, you are right ,it should be as you said